# Retrieving a SQL some rows having first two with date difference more than 120 seconds

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column that's a datetime. Anyone could suggest me if there's a way to retrieve next 20 records starting when I find first two ones that have a datediff > 120 seconds? Is that possible?...

It is like to find first stop of a coordinates list.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Cheers, 
Luigi

Comment: Could you provide example data, desired results and tag the question with the version of the RDBMS that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select top 20 * from Log
where dt >= (select Min(DT) from Log l -- not sure what you are looking for >= or =
            where Exists(Select * from Log l2 
                         where DateDiff(ss,l.DT,l2.DT)>120
                         and l.DT=(Select max(DT) from Log l3 where l3.DT<l2.DT)
                        ) )
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cba40/10)

Comment: Hello bummi, first thank you for the answer which looks good but in the table I have also a server_id where filter to because it's an huge table so trying that I got an error like: Difference of two datetime columns caused overflow at runtime (295,357 sec) - I have to say if I do: select top 23 * from Log where server_id = 2222 I get older data when I need to start from the latest indeed like adding "order by 1 desc"